# Using summernote to store html to a SQL Server 2014 database, using ASP classic

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, summernote

I'm using the Summernote WYSIWYG editor to allow users to send internal messages / emails from our app. However if a user is sending a message with multiple spaces (ie. Test       test), the plugin code view sets the html to (Test `&nbsp` `&nbsp` Test). When I try to insert that string into the database, the inserted field just saves the plain whitespace, not the non-breaking spaces.

How can I take the html from the editor, including the `&nbsp` and store that directly into the database without it becoming blank spaces?

Comment: By using replace? Replace(YourHTML, ' ', '&nbsp;')

Comment: Issue is this will replace spaces in between HTML tags with &nbsp as well

Comment: Well without some actual data to work with we are left guessing. Please provide some details so we can actually help here.

Answer (score 0):

By using replace you can replace string from the content

```
DECLARE @textwithhtml NVARCHAR(100) = 'Test &nbsp &nbsp Test'
SELECT REPLACE(@textwithhtml, '&nbsp',' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was the original messaging app used 2 forms, one for the initial text, then another when 'previewing' the form. When passing data to the second form the browser would just display the blank characters so the entities never got to the DB.